# How to grab command line arguments when application is reopen on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, command-line-arguments

I have to write an app on Mac OS X, that I want to open with command line with two arguments.
This is simple. I grab arguments using `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]`. But I need to grab new arguments when I reopen application. How to do that? ProcessInfo gives me arguments that I write only first time.
To be clear I do:
`open myapp.app --args -url1 http://apple.com -url2 /Desktop`
So I have in ProcessInfo two arguments: url1 and url2.

Now I want to reopen this aplication with another new arguments (applicattion is still working in background):
`open myapp.app --args -url1 http://somethingelse.com -url2 /Desktop/NewLibrary`
But when I use NSProcessInfo i have older arguments(`http://apple.com` and `/Desktop`).

How can I grab new arguments?

Sorry for my English :(

Comment: OS X only allows you to open an application once at a time. If it's already open, the `open` command simply brings it to the front, and the arguments are ignored.

Comment: It is possible to solve this problem in other way?

Comment: Use OSA to add a method to send parameters to the application, similar to the way URLs are sent to the browser.

Comment: you gotta write a second 'open'

Answer (score 2):

By default the `open(1)` command line tool will switch to an existing instance of your program. Since this will not call your program's main entry point the arguments will be ignored. They are set when the program launches and you have to launch a new instance of your program if you want to use it with other command line arguments.

Use `open -n` to launch a new instance of your program. This will launch a new instance even if another instance already exists.